# Store OpenCV boolean matrix on disk

Tags: c++, opencv, matrix

I have a float matrix of 1024x1024 and I want to keep sign of this matrix inside a file. For this purpose, I want to keep the sign matrix as `Matrix of boolean` which I fail to do.

Assume, my matrix is:

```
2.312, 0.232, -2,132
5.754,  -4,34, -3.23
-4.34,  -1.23, 7.9453
```

My output should be

```
 1,1,0
 1,0,0
 0,0,1
```

Since float is 4Byte and my matrix size is `10^20(1M)` the size is 4MB and boolean is 1bit and matrix size is 1M, I expect the bool mat to be around `1Mb=128KB` however, when I use `threshold` method in `opencv` my output file is `1MB` which means the file is saved as uchar(8bit).

I tried to use imwrite but it didn't work.

**EDIT:** I realized that I didn't mention speed is also another important factor for my tests. I'm loading approximately 10 million of 1K*1K matrix from disk.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

In OpenCV you can write

```
Mat input;
Mat A = (input >= 0);
```

Now the problem is that OpenCV has no bitmap data type. So the best you can get is Mat1u (unsigned char).

If you want to save space in your storage, you need to do it on your own. For example, you can use [libpng](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/libpng-manual.txt) to write out a PNG file of bit depth 1. Unfortunately, `imwrite` does not support setting that bit depth (it can write PNGs with bit depths 8 and 16).

If you want to write a compressed PNG with bitdepth 8, you can use `imwrite`:

```
std::vector<int> flags;
flags.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION);
flags.push_back(9);  // [0-9] 9 being max compression, default is 3
cv::imwrite("output.png", A, flags);
```

This will result in the best compression effort. Now you can use [Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) to compare the filesize against the same image stored with bit depth 1:

```
convert output.png -type Bilevel -define "png:bit-depth=1" -define "png:compression-level=9" output-1b.png
```

I tested with a random example image (see below).

- 8 bit, compressed PNG: 24,732 bytes
- 1 bit, compressed PNG: 20,529 bytes
- 8 bit, uncompressed PGM: 270,015 bytes
- 1 bit, uncompressed PBM:  34,211 bytes

As you can see, a compressed 8bit storage still beats uncompressed 1bit storage in this example.

[image: Example bitmap]

Comment: >= 0 will give 255 entries. try `A = (input >= 0)/255;`

Comment: Could you direct me a bit more about how to use this tool? Also, if I convert `sign Mat` to 8-bit, will it not be quite efficient as `imwrite` will compress the my data. I want to keep the matrix as small as possible in the disk but in RAM it is okay to keep it as 8-bits.

Comment: See my edited answer. In general when using the right compression parameter you might be happy enough with the 8-bits.

Comment: Thanks for detailed and really good answer however, when I use compression(like jpg,png etc), loading time decreases as compression factor increases. So, loading time of these compressed images are higher compared to 1MB uncompressed file. I added a line to my question. Thanks,